# Firefox WebExtensions inject script in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am new to javascript and writing web extensions. I want to write a web extension which changes the color of schedule entrys in my university planner. 
After some starting struggle I've been finally able to write a Firefox WebExtension that does exactly that on my uni's platform.
The problem is that my uni uses multiple platforms for different tasks which can either be accessed directly or via a platform that connects them all.
I've only been able to succesfully change the colors on the platform that directly shows me my schedule, not on the "general" platform.
After some more research I found the problem. The planner is loaded in an iframe and since both platforms have a different domain this seems to be a bigger problem then I thought.
I read a lot of confusing information on how to work with these cross-domain iframes which I 
couldn't really understand or am just unable to execute.

As far as I know I should be able to simply inject my script directly in the iframe and get the wanted result. But I haven't been able to do so. I didn't find any helpful information on how to do that with an WebExtension. I would really appreciate if someone could help me figure this out.

Maybe my idea is completly wrong and I need to try something else like using post message (which I didn't understand how to implement either) or something completly different. So anyways, I am looking forward to your replies.

Comment: Do not put answers within your question. This section is for Questions! Put your answer below in the Answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I know I should be able to simply inject my script directly
>   in the iframe and get the wanted result. But I haven't been able to do
>   so.

iframe is just like a web page and you can inject scripts into it like any web page.

There are the following considerations:

- Extension must have to correct `Permission` for iframe (which maybe
  from a different domain)
- Setting `all_frames: true` *(default is    false)* in 
  [content_scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts)

If you are injecting script by other method than `manifest.json`, let me know and I explain that too.

Comment: I already tried the setting of `all_frames` before but didn't get any results due to wrong URL-patterns. After you commented I looked at it again and got it to work just the way I wanted it, so thank you for sending me on the right track. I will edit my question with a part of my `manifest.json` for anyone being on the wrong track like me. One question remains. You wrote something about the correct `Permission`. What are you refering to? As I couldnt find any permissions that would help this case, nor do I use any in my current solution.

Comment: @rainbowschedule Depending on what the script does, if you only have permission for site A and the iframe is from a different site B, then some functions that require permission (e,g, XHR/fetch) may not functions as you expect since you only have permission for site A.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Thanks to *erosman*'s comment I looked at my `manifest.json` again and played around a bit to finally get my script to work the way I wanted. My problem was actually in wrong URL-patterns I provided. For anyone having a similar problem like me I will provide what would've saved my past me a lot of time.

Like *erosman* says:

> iframe is just like a web page and you can inject scripts into it like any web page.

Since I don't care about accessing the iframe's content from the parent document this means I can indeed just inject my script into the iframe directly and let it work there. The result will be visible on the webpage containing the iframe. In terms of Firefox WebExtensions this simply means setting the right parameters in your `manifest.json`. In `content_scripts` set `"all_frames": true` to allow your script to get injected into frames. Now you have to provide the URL of the webpage displaying the iframe aswell as the iframe's URL. Your `content_scripts` should look like:

```
    "content_scripts": [
        {
         "matches": ["*://*.webpage.org/*", "*://*.iframe.com/*"],
         "all_frames": true,
         "js": ["script.js"]
        }
     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry, but it is not posible to modify one website on an iframe if this iframe contains a website from other domain.

Maybe, you founded some examples with java script,  but if you see this examples in deep you'll find that they works because the domain is always the same...

The different origin forbiden this actions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I read that in theory it is not possible but that they were some workarounds for that. Is it not possible to somehow run my script in the .html of that iframe directly? I dont necessarily need any cross-domain activities. Just alter that without caring about it being displayed on another website.

Comment: Hi rainbowschedule. I have to say that I'm relly interested in this issue and I get it in my face several times. 
You can see this simple example: 
[link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_iframe_contentdocument2)

In this example, the life is so easy, because the iframe and the container page are in the same domain (and with all permision) and you can easy get access to everithing...

```var x = document.getElementById("myframe");
var y = x.contentDocument;
console.log(y.children[0].children[1].getElementsByTagName('P')[0].innerHTML)```

Comment: In my case I luckily didn't have to access the iframe from the parent document, so I can just inject my script directly in the iframe (see erosman's answer or my edited question). With my new gained knowledge and what I've read before I think you can still access an iframe from outside via [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) where you have to inject scripts in the parent document and the iframe to be able to communicate between them via this method. Maybe this can help you in the future.